# spinnaker | webhook as stage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, pipeline, spinnaker

Im Kind of new to GCP world, and trying to configure to hit an endpoint using the spinnaker - webhook as stage.

```
webURL :https://Testsite.com/s/subconnection/invoke?schedulerName=INV,method :POST,payload:{},content:application/json
```

Error:

```
Webhook failed: Error submitting webhook for pipeline 01EG6RQKB893ZkkkWPEQDDXH to https://Testsite.com/s/subconnection/invoke?schedulerName=INV
```

is returning status code 403, Do I need to add spinnaker user in my application rbac rules? pls help

Appreciate your help on this regard.

Thanks
Yugi

Comment: For questions or concerns pertaining to Spinnaker, I would like to direct you to the [Spinnaker Community page](https://spinnaker.io/community/). As they would be better suited in providing answers to your Spinnaker inquiries. In addition, please feel free to forward your issue to the [Github Spinnaker](https://spinnaker.io/community/#github) where you can find repos for all the services and documentation. You may file your issue [here](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues)

Answer (score 0):

The Spinnaker webhook stage doesn't really support any authentication methods out of the box. However, you can configure any headers you want, so you could optionally add one or more authentication headers there. If you use the custom webhook stage (where you configure the webhook in `orca-local.yml`), these custom headers will not be visible through the API or UI, **but they will be visible in the execution context**, so this should't actually be used for secrets. You can follow this issue for more information: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2787